# How can I get an out-bending \hbar with horizontal bar on Garamond Math?

Tags: unicode-math, math-fonts, garamond

[`garamond-math`](https://ctan.org/pkg/garamond-math) has a few stylistic sets. Stylistic set 6 makes `\hbar` have a horizontal bar (as opposed to a slanted bar), while stylistic set 10 makes all `h`'s bend outward, rather than inward. However, I can't figure out why they don't work together.

MWE with only stylistic set 10:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}[StylisticSet={10}]
\begin{document}
\(\hslash \ h\)
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

MWE with stylistic sets 6 and 10:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}[StylisticSet={6,10}]
\begin{document}
\(\hslash \ h\)
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:** This seems to be a known bug in `garamond-math` when using `LuaTeX` (my case), [as can be seen on the project's GitHub](https://github.com/YuanshengZhao/Garamond-Math/issues/14)

Comment: My first reaction was that "maybe the combined glyph does not exist", but looking in the font, it does indeed exist, as `uni210F.var.bar`. (+1)

Comment: Small update: I discussed this with Hans Hagen, and it seems that one has to be able to adapt ss06 and then ss10 (or in the other order), and we needed to adapt so that is now done in ConTeXt (I think this is the first time we met such a double feature in a math font), [see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2KIp.png). Probably a similar fix has to be done in LaTeX. But I don't know where it should be done.